# Python: Levenberg- Marquardt algorithm

Tags: python

I have a question about the Levenberg-Marquardt optimize method in Python:
Generally, the Lavenberg Maquardt is used for deterministic systems. Can I use it for stochastic model to estimate unknown parameters (inputs of my model).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement for the Levenberg Marquard algorithm is that you need to be able to calculate the jacoboan (derivative with respect to your parameter).

If this is the case for your problem then yes. I guess that it is not.

Perhaps the simplex algorithm is what you are looking for.